App Check failing in Cloud Function call from Flutter iOS app
I recently switched to a new Mac Mini from Linux and am currently setting up my development environment for a Flutter app + Firebase. On my previous machine, I was able to run the project without any problems. However, now when attempting to run the app in debug mode using the iOS emulator, the App Check verification fails during Cloud Function (v1) calls.
Cloud Function Code:
export const myCloudFunction = functions.https.onCall(async (
    data: any,
    context: functions.https.CallableContext
) => {
          if (!context.app) {
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
                'failed-precondition',
                'The function must be called from an App Check verified   
 app.');   

        }
...

My package.json:
...
    "dependencies": {
        ...
        "firebase-admin": "^12.3.0",
        "firebase-functions": "^4.0.2",
...

I've ensured the following configurations are correct in Firebase:

Android debug SHA keys have been added to the project setting.
App Check tokens are set appropriately for both Android and iOS emulator environments.

Despite these configurations, the Cloud Function call consistently fails when verifying the context.app.
Flutter Code:
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> callMyFunction(final dynamic parameters) async {
    final HttpsCallable callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable(
      'myCloudFunction',
    );

    final HttpsCallableResult res = await callable.call(parameters);
...
  }

My package.yaml
cloud_functions: ^4.7.4
firebase_app_check: ^0.2.1+15

